# How do I apply a model to predict and append the outcome for every observation in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I’m a relative novice with R (STATA refugee).

I have a dataframe, the observations of which are individual people. I also have a model of superannuation balances by age. I want to append the predicted superannuation balance to each person based on their age (age at last birthday).
The model was built to smooth grouped mean data for superannuation balances by age:

```
library(mgcv)
# Age bracket mid-points
x = seq(22, 62, 5)

# Male age-bracket super balance medians
y = c(6, 21, 42, 65, 75, 110, 137, 150, 230)

# Model the super as a function of age bracket
mod = gam(y ~ s(x, k = 8), family = Gamma(link = "log"))

# Predict the super balance for each age
pred = cbind(Age = 20:64, Super = predict(mod, data.frame(x = 20:64), "response"))

# Plot raw data and predictions for each year
plot(y ~ x, xlim = c(20, 64), ylim = c(0, 250), las = 1)
points(pred, col = "red")
```

I also have another dataframe, age, that has many vectors, one of which is age. What I would like to do is add a new vector to this dataframe that uses mod to predict that individual’s superannuation balance based on their age.
As an example dataframe (not my real data):

```
age=data.frame(seq(25,51,2))
```

An alternative would be to use the dataframe *pred* and to read off the relevant value for super from the appropriate age row and append that to *age*.

Unfortunately, I don’t know how to do either of these things. I figured there must be a way to use vapply() to run a prediction of the model over age but couldn’t make it work.
I also tried cbind():

```
cbind(age,y = predict(mod, newdata = age))
```

but got an error telling me the numbers of rows didn’t match.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind a dataframe to a vector/array in

```
cbind(age,y = predict(mod, newdata = age))
```

The output of predict is an array:

```
> class(predict(mod, data.frame(x = 20:64)))
[1] "array"
```

So you need to use sth like the following:

```
New <- data.frame(age=seq(25,51,2))

pred <-  cbind(Age = New$age, newdata = predict(mod, data.frame(x = New$age), "response"))
```

OR

```
pred <-  cbind(Age = seq(25,51,2), newdata = predict(mod, data.frame(x=seq(25,51,2)), "response"))
```

Comment: Thanks OmaymaS, I knew the answer was going to be something quite simple but I just couldn't nut it out from the help files, much appreciated. Your first suggestion worked a treat.